# reviews.list in google play store API is returning empty response

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-play, google-reviews

I want to retrieve all my reviews of an app using [`reviews.list`](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/reviews/list#http-request), a google developers API for extracting all reviews of an app from google play store.
When I try, I am getting empty response even though I have around 10 reviews in my app and this is the `statusCode: 200` and `statusMessage: 'OK'`,

But I am able to extract a review using `reviews.get` which indicates the bearer token and 0auth are all good and have got permissions too.

If anybody can help me out or can send a sample **curl**, it would be very helpful.

Here is my code

```
import axios from "axios";

const tokens = {
    "access_token": "12345access_token",
    "expires_in": 3548,
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher",
    "token_type": "Bearer"
};

const totalReviews = 1000;
const paginateNumCount = 150;
const packageName = 'package_name';


try{
let devrevReviews = await axios.get(`https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/${packageName}/reviews`,{
    headers : {
        Authorization : 'Bearer '+tokens.access_token
    },
});
console.log('devrevReviews', devrevReviews);
console.log('devrevReviews', devrevReviews.data);
} catch(error) {
    console.error('Error fetching reviews:', error.message);
}
```